# How can I use "chmod" command under the NTFS file system

Tags: git, ntfs, chmod

I wanted to change the file permission when I use "git", but the "chmod" didn't work.
How can I use "chmod" command under the NTFS file system?

Comment: What did you want to change the permissions to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-to-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition

The mode is determined by the partition's mount options (you cannot change it via chmod).

For '755' on files and '777' on directories you would use something like

```
sudo mount -t ntfs -o rw,auto,user,fmask=0022,dmask=0000 /dev/whatever /mnt/whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer by Casey Robinson points out you can't really chmod.

Here's how to use NTFS ACL within linux:

http://b.andre.pagesperso-orange.fr/permissions.html